# AWS identity-based policy error in Lambda script

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I have a lambda script to build a custom metric to notify us of errors in ECS Fargate python script. Below is the block of code used:

```
def get_error_count():
    
    log_streams = logs.describe_log_streams(
    logGroupName=log_group_name,
    orderBy='LastEventTime',
    descending=True, 
    limit=1)['logStreams']
    
    if log_streams:
        log_stream_name = log_streams[0]['logStreamName']
    
    print(f"Search for log steam {log_stream_name}")
    
    response = logs.filter_log_events(
            logGroupName=log_group_name,
            logStreamNames=[log_stream_name],
            filterPattern=filter_pattern,
            interleaved=False)
```

However when executing the script in lambda function getting the below error message:

> [ERROR] ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the DescribeLogStreams operation: User: arn:aws:sts::253579060874:assumed-role/cloudwatch_custom_metric-role-2c9dwrgu/cloudwatch_custom_metric is not authorized to perform: logs:DescribeLogStreams on resource: arn:aws:logs:us-west-1:253579060874:log-group:/ecs/github-pr:log-stream: because no identity-based policy allows the logs:DescribeLogStreams action

I already have logs:DescribeLogStreams policy attached for the resource and below is the policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "lambda:*",
                "iam:CreatePolicy",
                "iam:CreateRole",
                "iam:AttachRolePolicy",
                "iam:GetRole",
                "iam:ListRoles",
                "events:PutRule",
                "events:ListRules",
                "events:DeleteRule",
                "events:DescribeEventBus",
                "events:ListEventBuses",
                "events:ListTargetsByRule",
                "events:PutTargets",
                "events:RemoveTargets",
                "schemas:ListDiscoverers",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStacks",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "ecr:CreateRepository",
                "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:ListImages",
                "ecr:DescribeImages",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
                "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
                "ecr:PutImage",
                "ecr:UploadLayerPart",
                "ecr:BatchDeleteImage",
                "ecr:SetRepositoryPolicy",
                "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy",
                "ecr:DeleteRepository",
                "cloudwatch:GetMetricData",
                "cloudwatch:PutMetricData"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:PassRole",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "iam:PassedToService": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
                "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
                "logs:GetLogEvents",
                "logs:FilterLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetAccountPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:GetBucketPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:GetBucketPolicyStatus",
                "s3:GetBucketAcl",
                "s3:ListAccessPoints"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::latticework*/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketVersioning",
                "s3:CreateBucket",
                "s3:PutBucketOwnershipControls",
                "s3:PutBucketPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions",
                "s3:DeleteBucket",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::latticework*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::s3-skilljar-data*/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketVersioning",
                "s3:CreateBucket",
                "s3:PutBucketOwnershipControls",
                "s3:PutBucketPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions",
                "s3:DeleteBucket",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::s3-skilljar-data*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::s3-finance-data*/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketVersioning",
                "s3:CreateBucket",
                "s3:PutBucketOwnershipControls",
                "s3:PutBucketPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions",
                "s3:DeleteBucket",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::s3-finance-data*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::s3-aws-cost-data*/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketVersioning",
                "s3:CreateBucket",
                "s3:PutBucketOwnershipControls",
                "s3:PutBucketPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions",
                "s3:DeleteBucket",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::s3-aws-cost-data*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:ChangePassword",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::253579060874:user/${lambda_user}"
        }
      ]
    }
```

But still getting error. Please help

already an inline policy is present which did not work

Comment: resolved.. Issue is the policy is not mapped with Lambda script. Hence took the role assigned to lambda script and assigned the policy to the role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved.

Issue is the policy is not mapped with Lambda script role.
Hence took the role assigned to lambda script and assigned the policy to the role